# How can I extract all PCDATA (text) from an XML file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a bunch of XML files, along with the DTD, that each have a `<TEXT>` section. The DTD for the `TEXT` element looks like this:

`<!ELEMENT  TEXT      - -  (AGENCY* | ACTION* | SUMMARY* | DATE* | FOOTNAME* | FURTHER* | SIGNER* | SIGNJOB* | FRFILING* | BILLING* | FOOTNOTE* | FOOTCITE* | TABLE* | ADDRESS* | IMPORT* | #PCDATA)+ >`

Here is what an example XML file would look like:

```
<ROOT>
  ...
  <TEXT>
  Some text that I want to extract
  <SUMMARY> Some more text </SUMMARY>
  <AGENCY> 
     An agency
     <SIGNER> Bob Smith </SIGNER>
  </AGENCY>
  </TEXT>
  ...
</ROOT>
```

In the end, I want to extract

> Some text that I want to extract
>   Some more text
>   An agency
>   Bob Smith

However, each `<TEXT>` block obviously is not the same in terms of the elements / ordering, or how far down you go. Is there a way in Java using DOM that I can do this? I'd prefer to use DOM over SAX, but if it's much easier to use SAX, then so be it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XSLT stylesheet would work:

**UPDATE #2: I doubt this would work for you since you're actually using SGML and not XML. The give-away is that the element declaration you have in your question has tag minimization which is not allowed in XML.**

**UPDATE: Modified the XML input and XSLT to only display the text in the `<TEXT>` structure.**

**XML INPUT**

```
<ROOT>
  <IGNORE>ignore this data</IGNORE>
  <TEXT>
    Some text that I want to extract
    <SUMMARY> Some more text </SUMMARY>
    <AGENCY> 
      An agency
      <SIGNER> Bob Smith </SIGNER>
    </AGENCY>
  </TEXT>
  <IGNORE>ignore this data</IGNORE>
</ROOT>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(/ROOT/TEXT)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Some text that I want to extract Some
>   more text An agency Bob Smith

Note: This XSLT only works if TEXT is a child of ROOT. If TEXT might be nested more deeply, you can change the "select" to `select="normalize-space(//TEXT)"`.

Comment: You're right, it is SGML, but thus far it's been XML compatible

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of SAX, but for this, I think it would work nicely.

Just define a sax handler, but only use the `characters` method.  Then just throw the received characters in a `StringBuilder` and you're done.

```
public class textExtractor extends DefaultHandler {

  private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
      sb.append(ch[i]);
    }
  }

  public String getText(){
    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: I think I'll go with this approach. does the sax handler have to be its own class? or can I simply extend the parent class of my main method?

Comment: You can extend the parent class, but I wouldn't consider it a new approach.  If you don't want to make a specific class for this, you can use an anonymous class.